Various tattvas and how to enhance them?
As per astrology , a human body has five tattvas - Agni,vayu,Prithvi,Akash,and jal. How can each of these be enhanced in everyone’s body through physical practice and what are the effects that are produced in the body by these elements ? Thank you.
